# set a tag to docker-compose build result

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ci

I need to put a tag into docker-compose build image.

Here is an extract of my .gitlab-ci.yml scripts:

```
- docker build ---file=Dockerfile --tag=$CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE .
- docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p "$CI_BUILD_TOKEN" $CI_REGISTRY
- docker push $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE
```

Everything works fine.

But now, if I have to build multiple images into a single image:

```
- docker-compose build 
- docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p "$CI_BUILD_TOKEN" $CI_REGISTRY
- docker push $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE
```

On the first line, I cannot give tag argument to docker-compose.
That is my problem...

Thanks

Comment: In the `Context` subsection of this [doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build) it says: `Compose builds and tags it with a generated name, and use that image thereafter.`

Comment: build: ./dir
image: webapp:tag

Comment: Okay you mean it is not possible to combine 2 images into a single, with one tag?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a bit of confusion regarding the compose functionalities.

The compose file usually is needed to "set things up" for complete environments.

As @vahdet pointed out in the comment, you could specify `build:` and `image:` directives but they will be used only for the specified `service:` (i.e. one container) and not for the whole "docker-compose build image" (which actually doesn't make any sense to say because it could create more than one image and you can give every image a different `name:tag` ).

For the `"combine 2 images into a single, with one tag?"` question in the comment I think that the way you are looking for maybe could be to use the `FROM` directive in the Dockerfile to "join" them but I can't say it for sure since I don't know what you actually need to achieve.

Comment: in fact what i want to do is to deploy all images for my application in production. First i need to push them into the registry.

Comment: You could do that by specifying the  `image:` directive in the compose-file and then pushing each output image to the hub. Unfortunately there is no easy way ( [this is one](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/) ) to push multiple images simultaneously to the registry after the compose job